# Show Email body in bootstrap modal (CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to preview an email body in a modal (before sending the actual email). I load the modal via ajax call into the current page. Everything works fine BUT the email body has it's own css style which overwrites tags such as headings, body etc. in my original page, when loaded via jquery's ajax function.
Is there a way to "encapsule" the css somehow? The only thing I can think about is to rename all the tags in the email css. Is there a better way?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use two sets of conflicting CSS on the same page, you could use an iframe:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Thank you Tom. I stumbled upon that and used it quite often. I really don't like them, but I guess there's no way around this...

Comment: well, it is the easy way in this case.  AFAIK, there is no easy way to get two sets of CSS to live together (would love to know if there are any tools for that)